# List of installed applications by package

Tags: java, android, listview, android-package-managers

This is my problem: I can get the list of the installed applications in my device, but i need to have a list with only determinate apps in list. I mean, for example, i would show in list only my apps.. How can i do? Can i just look at the package name? Is there any other way to filter this list to show the applications i want? This is the code i'm using:

The adapter:

```
public class LocalAppListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {
    private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
    private Context context;
    private PackageManager packageManager;

    public LocalAppListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<ApplicationInfo> appsList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList);
        this.context = context;
        this.appsList = appsList;
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (null == view) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.local_app_list_row, null);
        }

        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = appsList.get(position);
        if (null != applicationInfo) {
            TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage);
            ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

            appName.setText(applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));
            packageName.setText(applicationInfo.packageName);
            iconview.setImageDrawable(applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager));
        }
        return view;
    }
};
```

And the class i use to get the list:

```
public class LocalAppList extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private LocalAppListAdapter listadaptor = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.local_app_list);

        packageManager = getPackageManager();

        new LoadApplications().execute();
    }



    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                    applist.add(info);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return applist;
    }

    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            listadaptor = new LocalAppListAdapter(LocalAppList.this, R.layout.local_app_list, applist);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.localAppList);
            list.setAdapter(listadaptor);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(LocalAppList.this, null, "Loading application info...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
}
```

So this is actually the full list with all applications.. I need find a way to filter the list showing for example only the google apps or which i want to show.

Comment: Implement your filter in `checkForLaunchIntent()`, only adding items to your result list if they meet your criteria.

Comment: In fact this was one of my idea but I couldn't find a way out.. Have you got any idea? Can you show me which implementations i need to do?

Comment: No, because I do not know what "for example only the google apps or which i want to show" means. In general, use the `ApplicationInfo` and `PackageManager` to identify whether or not this app belongs in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to display list of installed application in which it filters all the system level application i.e the application which can not be launched.

```
/**
 * This method is used to fetch all the application installed in device.
 * @param Context
 * @return List<ApplicationInfo>
 */
public static List<ApplicationInfo> getInstalledApplication(Context c) 
{
    List<ApplicationInfo> installedApps = c.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    List<ApplicationInfo> launchableInstalledApps = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
    for(int i =0; i<installedApps.size(); i++)
    {
        if(c.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(installedApps.get(i).packageName) != null)
        {
            //If you're here, then this is a launch-able app
            launchableInstalledApps.add(installedApps.get(i));
        }
    }
    return launchableInstalledApps;
}
```

I hope this will help.